# Pointer problems, array second position same as first in another array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc, realloc

I don't understand why the if statement: &*accountslist[1] == &*unameslist[0] is true. What is going on here? Is the problem with my realloc? Also, when I make accountlist[1] = NULL it seems that unameslist[0] also gets set to null. This makes me think that for some reason they end up pointing to the same location.

```
int loadInfo( char*** accountslist, 
          char*** unameslist, 
          char*** passlist )
{
    FILE* account_file = fopen( ACCOUNTS_LOCATION, "r" );
    FILE* uname_file = fopen( UNAMES_LOCATION, "r" );
    FILE* pass_file = fopen( PASSWORDS_LOCATION, "r" );

    char* nextAccount;
    char* nextUname;
    char* nextPass;

    fileWithNum( account_file, &nextAccount );
    fileWithNum( uname_file, &nextUname );
    fileWithNum( pass_file, &nextPass );

    *accountslist = (char**) malloc( sizeof(char*) );
    *unameslist = (char**) malloc( sizeof(char*) );
    *passlist = (char**) malloc( sizeof(char*) );

    *accountslist[0] = nextAccount;
    *unameslist[0] = nextUname;
    *passlist[0] = nextPass;

    int num_accounts = 1;

    while( nextAccount != NULL && nextUname != NULL &&
           nextPass != NULL )
    {
        *accountslist = (char**)realloc( *accountslist, 
                                 (num_accounts + 1) * sizeof(char*));
        *unameslist = (char**)realloc( *unameslist,
                               (num_accounts + 1) * sizeof(char*));
        *passlist = (char**)realloc( *passlist,
                             (num_accounts + 1) * sizeof(char*));
        fileWithNum( account_file, &nextAccount );
        fileWithNum( uname_file, &nextUname );
        fileWithNum( pass_file, &nextPass );
        printf( "%s\n" , *unameslist[0] );
        *accountslist[1] = NULL;
        if( &*accountslist[1] == &*unameslist[0] ) printf("WHY??\n" );
        printf( "%s, %s, %s\n" , *accountslist[0], *unameslist[0], *passlist[0]);

        *accountslist[num_accounts] = nextAccount;
        *unameslist[num_accounts] = nextUname;
        *passlist[num_accounts] = nextPass;

        printf( "%s, %s, %s\n" , *accountslist[num_accounts],
            *unameslist[num_accounts], *passlist[num_accounts]);
        num_accounts++;
    }

    fclose( account_file );
    fclose( uname_file );
    fclose( pass_file );

    return num_accounts;
}
```

Comment: [Don't cast the result of malloc (and friends)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845).

Comment: "Sorry my code isn't exactly formatted correctly"... Why didn't you correct it before posting then?

Comment: I removed the casts, but that didn't help. I meant to say sorry if its not formatted correctly. I don't think there is an issue.

Comment: IMO it's impossible to answer this question. My bet is that something's wrong with `fileWithNum`, I think this is the only place that has any connection to all three arrays, of course trusting c libraries are doing they work properly.

Answer (score 0):

`&*accountslist[1]` is equivalent to `accountslist[1]`, and `&*unameslist[0]` is equivalent to `unameslist[0]`, so you can rewrite that line as:

```
if( accountslist[1] == unameslist[0] ) printf("WHY??\n" );
```

The problem is that both `accountslist` and `unameslist` are pointers to your lists, i.e. they are of type `char ***`. They are not, themselves, arrays, so `unameslist[0]` is equivalent to `*unameslist` which is the address of your actual `unameslist` array, and `accountslist[1]` is actually out-of-bounds. Since that lands you in undefined behavior territory, you can't expect things to behave sensibly. Probably what's happening is that, prior to calling `loadInfo()`, you declared what `unameslist` points to immediately before what `accountslist` points to, so that `accountslist[1]` actually evaluates to the same address as `*unameslist`. This brief program demonstrates how this can happen:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void myfunc(char *** pp1, char *** pp2)
{
    /*  WARNING - undefined behavior ahead  */

    printf("pp1[1] is %p, pp2[0] is %p\n", (void *) pp1[1], (void *) pp2[0]);
}

int main(void)
{
    char ** p1 = (char **) 0xCC;
    char ** p2 = (char **) 0xFF;
    printf("p1 is %p, p2 is %p\n", (void *) p1, (void *) p2);
    printf("&p1 is %p, &p2 is %p\n", (void *) &p1, (void *) &p2);
    myfunc(&p2, &p1);
    return 0;
}
```

which, at least when I ran it, outputted:

```
paul@thoth:~/src/sandbox$ ./pdemo
p1 is 0xcc, p2 is 0xff
&p1 is 0x7fff8d138818, &p2 is 0x7fff8d138810
pp1[1] is 0xcc, pp2[0] is 0xcc
paul@thoth:~/src/sandbox$
```

and you can see how `pp1[1]` and `pp2[0]` are comparing equal due to the misuse of pointers. If you change `pp1[1]` to `&*pp1[1]` as you did, and likewise for `pp2[0]`, you'll see that you get the exact same result since they're equivalent.

What you actually meant is probably something like:

```
if( (*accountslist)[1] == (*unameslist)[0] ) printf("WHY??\n" );
```

Note that `[]` binds more tightly than `*` does, so `*accountslist[1]` is equivalent to `*(accountslist[1])`, when what you actually want is to deference `accountslist` first, so you need `(*accountslist)[1]`.

The short answer here is that you've got so much indirection you're confusing yourself and hugely misusing your pointers. As a result, practically none of your code is doing what you think it's doing. You should use some temporary variables to simplify and make it easier on yourself, e.g.:

```
char ** local_accounts_list = malloc(sizeof *local_accounts_list);
```

and then only at the end update your parameters with:

```
*accountslist = local_accounts_list;
```

You should also be checking the returns from `malloc()` and friends, `fopen()`, and any other function which might fail, which you never do. You can't be surprised when things don't work if you don't check for errors.

Comment: The issue ended up being with trying to use the vars that were passed in instead of using a temporary var then assigning it to the parameters at the end. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is fileWithNum if anyone is interested

```
int fileWithNum( FILE* fptr, char** word )
{
  //finished fixing
  int size;
  char* temp = NULL;
  fscanf( fptr, "%d", &size );
  if( size == -1) 
  {
    return 0;
  }
  int character = 0;
  temp = (char*) malloc( (size + 1) * sizeof(char));
  int current;
  for( current = 0; current < size; current++ )
  {
      if( fscanf( fptr, "%d", &character ) != 1 )
      {
          printf( "fscanf error\n" );
      }
      //printf( "%c\n" , character );
      //printf( "%d\n" , current );
      temp[current] = character;
  }
  temp[size] = 0; //end of string char
  *word = temp;
  printf( "End of filewithnum\n" );
  return 0;
}
```